# Get entire text from EditText

Tags: java, android

When I enter "sa" into EditText it takes only s. How can I pass my entire text?
Suppose I want to compare the text with the string "sa", how to get entire text from edittext?

```
e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.selection);
                  //edittext watcher
                e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                            int count) {
                                //getting edittext
                        String s1 =s.toString();

                        System.out.println("edittext :" + s1);
                        // compare edittext string woth arraylist
                        if (s1.length() >=1) {

 //taking stringbuilder to add list items                           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            for(inti=0;i<orginalarrayelements.length;i++)
                            {
        //compare edittext with arraylist with region matches                       if(orginalarrayelements[i].regionMatches(true, 0, s1, 0, s1.length())){
                                        sb.append(orginalarrayelements[i] +",");
                                        System.out.println("modified array: " + sb);
                            }
```

}

Comment: Try to fix your text, I cannot understand what you are trying to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the full text from your `EditText`, right?

`OnTextChanged` gets called every time your text changes, so it will always only contain either one letter or null if you deleted a letter.

If you want to get the full text, call `e.getText().toString();` in your `OnTextChanged`, `OnClick` on a Button or anywhere else.

By the way: rethink you names: "e" is not a name you should use. Take something like "`editText`", "`myEditText`", "`usernameEditText`",...